# Symfony How to Generate Entities from an Existing Database

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have my database and it's work very good with my entities and I add 4 tables to the base how can I generate entities for this 4 tables ?? And I wan generate only for this 4 tables not all because my base it's very complicated ? And I have many Index and many Functions in this 4 tables how Can I use it if that's possible ??

Answer (score 1):

It is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

You can use `doctrine:mapping:import`. Check `php bin/console help doctrine:mapping:import` for more details.

Comment: This commande used to generate all the database

Comment: @HaythemHedfi that's why I recommended you to check the help for this command. It allows you to specify `--filter` option.

Comment: I use it but it doesnt work

Comment: php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "BOGeneralBundle" xml --filter=StBaseGeoRegions

Comment: and the console display this message
Database does not have any mapping information.